# awk convert quoted date time format to unixtimestamp

Tags: unix, awk

I need to convert date time format value (in the first field of lof file) to epochtime
To give you an example. I have a log file looking like this

> 2018-07-0321:36@/foo/bar/filename.txt

and I need it to look like this

> 1530668160.0000000000@/foo/bar/filename.txt

thanks for any help. Note I am not having seconds field in first string

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I have found answer through similar post